# How to remove or hide the LunchScreen.storyboard in xcode with react native

Tags: xcode, react-native

1. I just removed launchscreen.storyboard in Xcode.
2. I will use my own splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, but you can try one of the following:

1. Use the react-native-hide-splash-screen package.
2. Use the react-native-launch-screen package.
3. Modify your app's Info.plist file to include the "UILaunchStoryboardName" key with a value of "None".
4. Remove the "Main storyboard file base